# How to set http connection limit in Go language

Tags: http, go

I have set a limit to the number of simultaneous HTTP connections to be made at any given time. I am using netutil for the same. Below is the code.

```
func Listen() {
    connectionCount := 10  //Set limit to number of connections
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", sshListen)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if useProxyProtocol {
        l = &proxyproto.Listener{
            Listener:           l,
            ProxyHeaderTimeout: time.Second * 10,
        }
    }

    for {
        //Accept connections
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        connectionCount ++
        if err != nil {
            atomic.AddInt64(&stats.Stats.FailedConnections, 1)
            continue
        }
        l = netutil.LimitListener(l, connectionCount)
        log.Infow("Number of connections", log.Fields{"Connections": connectionCount})
        go neconn(conn)
    }
}
```

This is still accepting more number of connections when trying out the code. Can someone please help with what else can be done?

Comment: Use an atomic.Int32 to count connections.  Subtract from the count when a connection is closed. Increment the count when a connection is accepted.  If count is greater than limit, then close connection.

Comment: Or use a counting semaphore, easily realized via an buffered channel.

Comment: @CeriseLimón  added "atomic.AddInt32(&stats.Stats.AcceptedConnections, 1)" instead of "connectionCount ++" . How do I subtract the count?

Comment: @Volker Semaphore is something new for me. I would want something that I can change in the existing code?

Comment: Add -1 to subtract.

Comment: Yup. This works. I added an if statement and break out of the loop once the max number of connections is reached. Thanks!